# JFace Tree Viewer: Listener for node expansion?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, jface

I have a JFace tree and need to store each parent element that gets expanded **before** the expansion is finished in a variable, because I need a reference to the expanded element for a method in my Label Provider which seems to be called directly after clicking the expander arrow.

I know that the ITreeViewerListener Interface can be used to get an element **after** it has been fully expanded, but not while it is expanding (=directly after clicking the elements expander arrow). This way, I get a nullpointer exception when trying to use a reference to the expanded element in my Label Provider, because the Label Provider gets called directly after the elements expander arrow is clicked and does not wait for the element to be fully expanded.

I tried using the ISelectionChangedListener. Unfortunately, the element does not get selected when its expander arrow is clicked, so ISelectionChangedListener is not triggered.

After some research, I found that there's a [TreeWillExpandListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/TreeWillExpandListener.html) for swing. This seems to be exactly what I need, but I couldn't get it to work with my JFace Tree Viewer. Is there any way to get this done using JFace?

Comment: You should really design the objects returned by your content provider so that they can provide the parent when the label provider needs them.

Comment: There are multiple parent and child objects, while one/the same object can be contained by several parent objects. i.e.:
+parent 1:
  -child a
  -child b / 
+parent 2:
  -child a;
in this case, child a is contained by two parents. I have a second column in which I want to display the count of each child element in the particular parent element, because the same object could be added multiple times to a parent. In order to have the LabelProvider display the correct count of a child element, I need to tell it which parent element to check. I assumed that this can only be done via user selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to greg-449, I had a closer look at the Content Provider.

Initially, I had seperate classes for my Label Provider and Content Provider. By creating a single class which implements ITableLabelProvider and ITreeContentProvider, I could join them together and thus give my Label Provider the possibility to access each elements parent element without needing a selection.